# Change Carousel active indicator as it scrolls or is selected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have build a boostrap Carousel and modified the indicators to be the map markers with icons in the middle. They rollover fine, but what i was hoping to add is when the corresponding slide below is active they show the hover state.

http://women.hemophilia.on.ca/

What is tied so far is adding the class, as it scrolls, Carousel automatically changes the active class to each item

```
.marker-recently:hover, .marker-recently .active{
    background-image:url(/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/marker-recently-over.png);
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
               
                  <span data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="marker-size marker-recently active"></span>
               
                  <span data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="marker-size marker-pregnant"></span>
               
                  <span data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="marker-size marker-period"></span>
               
                  <span data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3" class="marker-size marker-menopause"></span>
               
                  <span data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4" class="marker-size marker-concerns"></span>
               
                  <span data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5" class="marker-size marker-continuing-eduation"></span>
        </div>
        <br clear="all" />
        <div class="carousel-inner">
               
          <div class="carousel-item active">
         
            <div class="container">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                   <img class="first-slide" src="http://women.hemophilia.on.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/icon-recently-dianosed.png" alt="Recently Diagnosed" width="81" height="95">
                  <p>I am recently diagnosed with a bleeding disorder and I am looking to learn.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
           
          <div class="carousel-item ">
           
            <div class="container">
              <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
                <img class="first-slide" src="http://women.hemophilia.on.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/icon-pregnant.png" alt="Pregnant" width="71" height="95">
                <p>I am pregnant or trying to get pregnant and I have a bleeding disorder.</p>
               
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
           
          <div class="carousel-item ">
           
            <div class="container">
              <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
                <img class="first-slide" src="http://women.hemophilia.on.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/icon-period.png" alt="Started my period" width="77" height="95">
                <p>I am about to get my period or I have just started my period recently.</p>
               
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
           
          <div class="carousel-item ">
           
            <div class="container">
              <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
                 <img class="first-slide" src="http://women.hemophilia.on.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/icon-menopause.png" alt="Menopause" width="67" height="95">
                <p>I have started menopause and want to know bleeding  disorder related issues.</p>
               
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
           
          <div class="carousel-item ">
           
            <div class="container">
              <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
                 <img class="first-slide" src="http://women.hemophilia.on.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/icon-new-concern.png" alt="Bleeding Concerns" width="116" height="95">
                <p>I have a bleeding concerns, could I have a bleeding disorder?</p>
               
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
           
          <div class="carousel-item ">
           
            <div class="container">
              <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
                 <img class="first-slide" src="http://women.hemophilia.on.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/icon-continuing-ed.png" alt="Continuing Education" width="73" height="95">
                <p>I have had a bleeding disorder for awhile now and I am looking for new info.</p>
               
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
             
       
           
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true">&#9664;</span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true">&#9654;</span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
```

css

```
/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
  position: inherit;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
     
     z-index: 10;
      color: #000;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
}
.carousel-caption p {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 40px;
 
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel-item {
  height: 220px;
  background-color: #f8f4ed;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.carousel-item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 81px;
  height: 95px;
}

.carousel-inner{
    margin-top: 90px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    width: 1120px;
    border-bottom: 20px #cf3537 solid;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}


.carousel-control-next-icon, .carousel-control-prev-icon {
    font-size: 30px;
    background-image: none;
    color: #cf3537;
    margin-top: -100px;
 
}

.carousel-indicators {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    max-width: 1120px;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 250px;
    top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url(images/graphic-road.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom;
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.marker-size {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: 100px 134px;
}

.marker-recently{
    background-image:url(/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/marker-recently.png);    
}

.marker-recently:hover, .marker-recently .active{
    background-image:url(/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/marker-recently-over.png);
}


.marker-pregnant{
    background-image:url(/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/marker-pregnant.png);
}

.marker-pregnant:hover, .marker-pregnant .active{
    background-image:url(/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/marker-pregnant-over.png);
}


.marker-period{
    background-image:url(/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/marker-period.png);
}

.marker-period:hover, .marker-period .active{
    background-image:url(/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/marker-period-over.png);
}


.marker-menopause{
    background-image:url(/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/marker-menopause.png);
}

.marker-menopause:hover, .marker-menopause .active{
    background-image:url(/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/marker-menopause-over.png);
}


.marker-concerns{
    background-image:url(/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/marker-concerns.png);    
}

.marker-concerns:hover, .marker-concerns .active{
    background-image:url(/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/marker-concerns-over.png);
}


.marker-continuing-eduation{
    background-image:url(/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/marker-continuing-eduation.png);
}

.marker-continuing-eduation:hover, .marker-continuing-eduation .active{
    background-image:url(/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/marker-continuing-eduation-over.png);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already did it right in your `CSS` sheet, but you just wrote it wrong.

You wrote:

```
.marker-concerns:hover, .marker-concerns .active
```

so you are sniping an element with  class `active` as a child of element with class `marker-concerns` (which it does not exist). Remove the space so when you call:

```
.marker-concerns.active
```

You are actually calling an element with BOTH classes (which is what you need).
Remove the blank space from all six `css` lines ans it should work.

Comment: Thank you Alvaro